# Matplotlib histogram2d normalize not equal 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Having one of those days, I can't get my head around what is going on. I have a tool which generates 2D histograms from arrays (Numpy arrays) of X,Y,Z coords (Z is unimportant at the minute). I need the results to be normalised so I can do some further calculation. However, when using the normed=True command, the sum of the array is always somewhere around 0.000006.

I am looking to normalise the whole histogram, so all array elements would add up to 1. Setting normed to False correctly returns the number of samples in the bin, but obviously this isn't normalised. I have tested it with arrays from 3k elements all the way up to 30k and still the same problem. For the record my data includes minus coordinates on all 3 axes.

Code is as follows:

```
def histogrammer(coords):      # coords is a 3D numpy array

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], bins=(50, 50), range=([-10000.0,10000.0],[-10000.0,10000.0]), normed=True)
H.shape, xedges.shape, yedges.shape
extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[-1], xedges[0]]

global displayHistograms
if displayHistograms == True:
    print('Displaying:')
    plt.imshow(H, extent=extent, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

print('{0:.30f}'.format(np.sum(H)))    # Debug normalisation

return H
```

I run this code for two arrays, generating two different histograms. The print statements for each:

```
0.000006250000000000000299510850
0.000006250000000000002840609692
```

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`normed=True` normalizes the volume (i.e. sum of `binarea*binheight`) to `1`, not the sum of heights. Because that's the way you would normalize a histogram usually, since normalized histogram is an estimate for probability density function.

If you want to make the sum of heights one, just divide the unnormalized values by total number of points:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], bins=(50, 50), range=([-10000.0,10000.0],[-10000.0,10000.0]))
H_normalized = H/float(coords.shape[0])
```

Comment: Right, I understand now! Interestingly now I'm getting `0.999999999999998778754672912328` after the normalisation you outlined above. I have checked and the total items in `H` is the same as in the `coords` array.

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I changed the precision of the print statement to .2f and the number was rounded to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Setting normed=True gives the bin-density, rather than the fraction of total items in the bin.  You will need to calculate this from bin width or manually.